# How can I rotate 'LOCAL' orientation in 2.82 python Script

Tags: python, scripting

Blender : 2.82
Windows 10

This is my code
and i want to rotate 'Global' and 'Local' both

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

this_scene = bpy.context.scene
view_layer = bpy.context.view_layer
override = bpy.context.copy()
override['selected_objects'] = bpy.data.objects["MyOBject"]
rot_obj = override['selected_objects']
now_pos = rot_obj.rotation_euler[0:3]

rot_obj.rotation_euler = now_pos + np.deg2rad(np.array([10, 10, 0]))
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=np.deg2rad(50), orient_axis='Y', orient_type='LOCAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, -4.37114e-08, 1), (0, -1, -4.37114e-08)), orient_matrix_type='LOCAL', constraint_axis=(False, True, False), mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False, release_confirm=True)
```

this works fine in python console in line by line.
but the problem is 'Run Script' (there are about 200 ea files exist)

when i Run Scripts by pushing 'Run Script' button
"MyOBject" rotates only GLOBAL orientation.

i found some code Blender 2.82 Python API but don't know how, don't know what it is ...

bpy.types.TransformConstraint, bpy.types.TransformOrientation, bpy.types.TransformOrientationSlot, bpy.context.scene.transform_orientation_slots

and one more, is there fully functional intellisense(autocomplete) in blender? 
or API using guide? the documentation is quite not kind:(

(so many def, function, class are not work even in console)

please help ..